# Devise - Unable to login with username Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, authentication, devise

I'm having trouble logging into Devise with the username, the email is not giving me any issues, btw. I followed all of the instructions, and I successfully signed users up with their username/email. The error that I'm receiving is below.

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-04-29 15:09:09 -0400
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"âœ“", "authenticity_token"=>"RL7IXaRa6OOEValataRLI6x3OIky0bOiEstqzJCvYgM5TTg0N3ydRQTY/FjBNXgPHIkuShp2JECeTfI7OM1aqQ==", "user"=>{"login"=>"jonsnow200", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Log in"}
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (username = 'jonsnow200' OR lower(email) = lower('jonsnow200'))  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 7ms (ActiveRecord: 1.5ms)
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"âœ“", "authenticity_token"=>"RL7IXaRa6OOEValataRLI6x3OIky0bOiEstqzJCvYgM5TTg0N3ydRQTY/FjBNXgPHIkuShp2JECeTfI7OM1aqQ==", "user"=>{"login"=>"jonsnow200", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Log in"}
  Rendered users/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (16.0ms)
  Rendered navigation/_navbar.html.erb (9.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 2339ms (Views: 2229.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Application_Controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def redirect_back_or(path)
    redirect_to request.referer || path
  end

  protected
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:username, :avatar, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :avatar_cache, :remove_avatar) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:login, :username, :email, :password, :remember_me) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:username, :display_name, :age, :gender, :country_id, :email, :avatar, :avatar_cache, :remove_avatar, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password) }
  end
end
```

devise.rb

```
config.authentication_keys = [:login]
config.case_insensitive_keys = [:email]
config.strip_whitespace_keys = [:email]
config.skip_session_storage = [:http_auth]
config.stretches = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 10
config.reconfirmable = true
config.confirmation_keys = [:username]
config.expire_all_remember_me_on_sign_out = true
config.password_length = 8..72
config.reset_password_keys = [:username]
config.reset_password_within = 6.hours
config.scoped_views = true
config.sign_out_via = :delete
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :login
  validate :validate_username
  friendly_id :username, use: :slugged
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :token_authenticatable #:encryptable

  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
  validates :avatar, :presence => true
  validates_integrity_of :avatar
  validates_processing_of :avatar
  validates :username,
            :presence => true,
            format: {with: /\A[a-zA-Z0-9]*\z/, message: "may only contain letters and numbers."},
            :uniqueness => {
                :case_sensitive => false, length: {maximum: 16}
            }
  validates :email,
            :presence => true,
            :uniqueness => {
                :case_sensitive => false, length: {minimum: 5}
            }

  def validate_username
    if User.where(email: username).exists?
      errors.add(:username, :invalid)
    end
  end

  def self.find_first_by_auth_conditions(warden_conditions)
    conditions = warden_conditions.dup
    if login = conditions.delete(:login)
      where(conditions.to_hash).where(["username = :value OR lower(email) = lower(:value)", {:value => login}]).first
    else
      where(conditions.to_hash).first
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to swap the finder_method for the username/email since I changed the recovery process to access usernames/emails

```
def self.find_first_by_auth_conditions(warden_conditions)
    conditions = warden_conditions.dup
    if login = conditions.delete(:login)
      where(conditions).where(["lower(username) = :value OR lower(email) = :value", { :value => login.downcase }]).first
    else
      if conditions[:username].nil?
        where(conditions).first
      else
        where(username: conditions[:username]).first
      end
    end
  end
```